# Need cells to be blank if SUMIF cells are blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the following formula

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C$3:C$10<>""))=0,"",SUMIF($B$3:$B$10,$B11,C$3:C$10))
```

to leave blank cells unless data exists but I need it to leave a blank cell if data for the specific type doesn't exist. Every zero in the bottom 3 rows, which are my calculation rows, I want to be blank.

On the 9th there were no pears so I want the pears cell to be blank.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more clear.  Nobody can see "the bottom 3 rows", or the absence of pears in the 9th row. Please upload a screenshot of your data to imgur.com, then edit your question, and add a link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is purely for presentation purposes only.
Right click the cells and apply this custom formatting:
`0;-0;`
[image: Custom Formatting for zero results]